# 'for' loop within a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I have a dataframe with four columns "Lat, Long, age, age_s". I want to write a function (which contains a for loop) to apply to the age_s column of the dataframe.

Here is the code I have written so far (but it is not working):

```
def bathy(row):
    x = 0
    for a in index:
        x += (1. / ((1. + 2. * a)**2.))* (math.exp(-(k*((1.+2.*a)**2.)*(pi**2.)*row['age_s'])/(zp**2.)))
    return (zr + (1. - (8. / pi**2. * x)) * (((rhom * ap * deltaT * zp) / (2. * (rhom -rhow)))))/ 1e3

tmp['bathy'] = tmp.apply(bathy, axis=1)
```

Can someone please point out where I've gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your error traceback in the question. It helps others understand the problem better! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
tmp['bathy'] = tmp.apply(lambda row: bathy(row), axis=1)
```